# Limit numbers entered in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this working however, it need to limit the parts of the text input. For instance, I have to limit `DD` to allow upto 31, `MM` to limit upto 12 and limit `YYYY` from 1900 to 2018

Any idea how to go about this?

```js
$('[data-type="dateofbirth"]').mask('00/00/0000');

function submitBday1() {
  var Q4A = "";
  var Bdate = document.getElementById('bday1').value;
  var darr = Bdate.split('/');
  var temp = darr[0];
  darr[0] = darr[1];
  darr[1] = temp;
  var fmtstr = darr.join('/');
  var Bday = +new Date(fmtstr);
  Q4A += ~~((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
  var theBday = document.getElementById('resultBday1');
  theBday.innerHTML = Q4A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-type="dateofbirth" maxLength="10" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a date input?

Comment: As @Luca implies: use a date input (`<input type="date">`): [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pLobj1xu/).

Comment: The client didn't want the date popup. I had used it earlier. Wants to type the date instead.

Comment: You can hide the popup, would that work?

Comment: Validating the text in the input using regex expressions could also be an option.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Sadly, No.

Comment: @thebrownkid Any example how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jquery.mask.min.js](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/354) library

> is not meant to be a validation library, just a way to automatically insert characters like punctuation. Validation would have to be done separately.

Hence, I would suggest to use [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask):

```js
$('[data-type="dateofbirth"]').inputmask({alias: 'datetime', inputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/4.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-type="dateofbirth" maxLength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Comment: This is amazing! btw, any idea if we could limit the year too?

Comment: Got it working. `$('[data-type="dateofbirth"]').inputmask({alias: 'datetime', yearrange: { minyear: 1900, maxyear: 2018 }, inputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'});`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use `<select>`:

```html
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>31</option>
</select>
```

2. Use `<input type="number" min="1" max="31">`:

```html
<label>Day
<input type="number" min="1" max="31" step="1" value="1" />
</label>
<label>Month
<input type="number" min="1" max="12" step="1" value="1" />
</label>
<label>Year
<input type="number" min="1900" max="2018" step="1" value="2018" />
</label>
```

Note: not all browsers support `number` as an input type, so please make sure it'll work on the platforms that you need it to work on.

Comment: `select options` is out of question. `number` is also not possible since that method works if I have 3 input fields. I have just 1 input field.

Answer (score 0):

You want to validate your inputs beyond what hmlt5 can do, so a plugin like jQuery Validate would be a good idea.

You may have to research basic usage first, but it is fairly straightforward and very useful.

First, to validate your birth date, moment.js will make it easy:

`moment(document.getElementById('bday1').value, 'DDMMYYY').isValid()`
`moment(document.getElementById('bday1').value, 'DDMMYYY').year() <= 2018` or better
`moment(document.getElementById('bday1').value, 'DDMMYYY').year() <= moment().year()`

To tie this into jQuery validate, you can add the below as a custom method of jQuery Validate and set a rule for your "date" input `validBirthDate : true`

```
$.validator.addMethod('validBirthDate', function(value){
    return moment(value, 'DDMMYYY').isValid() && moment(value, 'DDMMYYY').year() <= moment().year();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('[data-type="dateofbirth"]').mask({
   alias: 'datetime',
   inputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
   min: '31/12/1900',
   max: '31/12/2018'
});
```